# Trying to get for looped list items to sent to flask results page

Tags: python, flask

I'm dropping an email .eml file into a flask-dropzone and getting all the urls from the email.. Some of the emails a malformed so I'm taking that list and running it against results.get to get a list of valid urls.  I want to return that list to a results page.

```
@app.route('/upload/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def uploadn():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files.get('file')

        #entries = os.listdir ( 'uploads/' )
        #for entry in entries:
         #   print ( entry )
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_PATH'], f.filename))
        testme = f.filename
        file = open ( "uploads/" + str(testme), 'r' )
        text = file.read ()
        #print (text)
        testparse = eml_parser.eml_parser.get_uri_ondata(text)
        print (testparse)
        #parsed_eml = eml_parser.eml_parser.decode_email_b ( text, include_raw_body=text )
        #print(parsed_eml)
        #datareturns = json.dumps ( parsed_eml, default=json_serial )
        #json_data = json.loads ( datareturns )
        #print (json_data)
        #context = ssl._create_unverified_context ()
        for urls in testparse:
            try:
                urlresponsecode = requests.get ( urls )
                #print ( "URL " + urls + " is valid and exists on the internet" )
                new = []
                testlist = new.append(urls)
                print (testlist)
            except requests.ConnectionError as exception:
                pass


        return render_template ( "results.html", new=new )

    return render_template ( "upload.html" )
```

---

Results template page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div class="container" align="left">
        <p>{{ testparse }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `new` list to your template. Is that not what you are intending to render? If not, just pass whatever you want to render to `render_template` and do

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>Title</title> </head> <body class="body"> <div class="container" align="left">
{% for item in new %}
 <p>{{ item }}</p> </div> </body> </html>
{% endfor %}
```